# MultiThreading Logical Issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, network-programming

I have following class that performs caching between browser and webserver and works as proxy server. I have given just simple class definition.

Here In this class I have three methods.

1. RequestNewCacheFilePath returns unique id (incremented by 1 after each function call) that will be used to save network file into disk.
2. CommitNewCacheFilePath commits unique id into dictionary after file download. Until download its id will be 0 into dictionary.

In RequestNewCacheFilePath function one dictionary item added with value 0. That means resource downloading is in progress for that resource. And when file download completes dictionary is updated with its actual unique cache id. But **sometimes** In CommitNewCacheFilePath function debug assertion fails in multithreaded scenario.

```
public class CacheManager
{
    const string INDEX_FILE_NAME = "index.txt";

    Dictionary<string, int> _dictResources = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public IAppServer Server { get; private set; }

    object _syncCacheIdObject = new object();
    int _cacheId;

    public string CacheDirectoryPath { get; private set; }

    public CacheManager(IAppServer server)
    {
        server.ThrowIfNull("server");

        Server = server;

        CacheDirectoryPath = (server.Config as ProxyServerConfig).CacheDirectoryPath;
        if (CacheDirectoryPath.IsEmpty())
            CacheDirectoryPath = Path.Combine("C:\\", Application.ProductName);

        if (!Directory.Exists(CacheDirectoryPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(CacheDirectoryPath);

    }

    public int GetCacheId(string key)
    {
        int value;
        if (_dictResources.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            return value;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public string RequestNewCacheFilePath(string key)
    {
        int cacheId;

        lock (_syncCacheIdObject)
        {
            cacheId = ++_cacheId;
        }

        lock (_dictResources)
        {
            if (_dictResources.ContainsKey(key))
                return null;
            else
            {
                _dictResources[key] = 0;
                return Path.Combine(CacheDirectoryPath, cacheId + ".cache");
            }
        }
    }

    public void CommitNewCacheFilePath(string key, string cachedFilePath)
    {
        int cachedId = int.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cachedFilePath));

        lock (_dictResources)
        {
            Debug.Assert(_dictResources[key] == 0);

            _dictResources[key] = cachedId;
        }
    }

    public void RevertNewCacheFilePath(string resourcePath)
    {
        lock (_dictResources)
        {
            _dictResources.Remove(resourcePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the code look like that calls RequestNewCacheFilePath? What triggers a call to that method with a particular key?

Comment: Allowing RequestNewCacheFilePath() to return null is a strong code smell, that has to be hiding a concurrency bug.  Add tracing to debug this.

Comment: @All Yes, I found bug in my other code. Actaully CommitNewCacheFilePath is called for multiple times for different resources. So it occured. Thanks.